# make popover appear only after a few seconds of hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Using bootstrap popover, I can do:

```
$("#example").popover({ 
     trigger: "hover"
});
```

so the popover react to a hover instead of a click ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Vq8Y/1/)). However - I want to set it to appear after a few seconds of hover (say 2). Is there any simple way to do it? I've searched everywhere but couldn't find any anything similar...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be the `delay` option

```
$('#elem').popover({
    trigger: "hover",
    delay: {show : 2000, hide : 0}
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Vq8Y/2/)

Comment: Ah of course. because who would've thought to look for it in **the documentation**. I feel silly. Thanks =]

Comment: And the link to documentation (BS 4.1): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/#usage